# Change src img directive or filter angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm trying to implement a resize for images, so I don't request a big image file. Therefore, I need to change the 'src' of the img tag to redirect it to a resize service.

I have been trying to make a directive which specify the size that I want to use and $observe the ngSrc.

```
.directive('resizeTo', function ( imageResizeFactory ) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {

            var sizes = attrs.resizeTo.split('x')

            if ( !sizes.length ) {
                throw new ReferenceError('no sizes provided');
            }

            if ( el[0].nodeName !== 'IMG' ) {
                throw new ReferenceError('type of node must be IMG');
            }

            //
            // apply same width and height
            if ( sizes.length === 1 ) {
                sizes.push.apply(sizes, sizes);
            }

            var observer = attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function ( newSrc ) {
                _updateSrc( newSrc );
            });

            function _updateSrc( src ) {
                var resizeUrl = imageResizeFactory( src, sizes[0], sizes[1] )
                el.attr('src', resizeUrl);
            }
        }
    }
})
```

This doesn't work since there is a conflict between this directive and the angular ngSrc directive, modifying again the src attribute after it has been modified in my custom directive. I was wondering if there is a work-around to modify the 'src' after it has been interpolated by ngSrc.

I was also thinking to use a filter, instead. What do you think about it?
I would like to get some feedback on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prioritize you can use the [priority](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) config param of a directive.

This way you'll be sure that your directive is being applied after ngSrc :

> priority
>
> When there are multiple directives defined on a single DOM element,
>   sometimes it is necessary to specify the order in which the directives
>   are applied. The priority is used to sort the directives before their
>   compile functions get called. Priority is defined as a number.
>   Directives with greater numerical priority are compiled first.
>   Pre-link functions are also run in priority order, but post-link
>   functions are run in reverse order. The order of directives with the
>   same priority is undefined. The default priority is 0.